# Отслеживание запуска процессов из определенного каталога Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, процесс, поиск-библиотек

Какими библиотеками и функциями можно воспользоваться для отслеживания процессов, запускаемых из определенного каталога под `Windows` из `Python3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import win32com.client, os

def find_proc_name_by_path(path):
    for proc in win32com.client.GetObject('winmgmts:').instancesof('win32_process'):
        p_path = proc.properties_[7].value
        if p_path:
            p_path = os.path.split(p_path)
            if p_path[0] == path:
                yield p_path[1]

for proc_name in find_proc_name_by_path('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application'):
    print(proc_name)  # 'chrome.exe'
```

Comment: Я правда уже решил задачу через win32api но все равно спасибо. Недавно только начал изучение питона, пригодится информация.